# I can not able to render the component using routing?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

here app is function is not able yo call from the route so guys can u please provide me the right solution for this

Comment: check this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: <Route path="/" component={App}>
    {/* <IndexRoute component={Home} /> */}
    <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/login" activeuser component={Home} />
    <Route path="/agent" activeagent component={Home} /> from this file ...am not bale to call the app function

Comment: you have to use Route in app not app in route

Comment: take look on example on given link

Comment: provide some more code will help us to help you

Comment: i have update my react to latest one so i can not able to lead the componenets buddy please help out form this issue

Comment: provide code in the question it's really very hard to type from the image I will show you what you are doing wrong

Comment: stack over flow is not user friendly its seem getting so many errors

Comment: you can add codepane link here with your source code

Comment: how can i contact you buddy jatin parmar

Comment: Please help me out